# How to get list of keys from a [key: string]: string structure in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, data-structures, key-value

New to Typescript. I need to pull all the keys from a key/value data structure into a list (preferably a set)of its own.
Example:

```
export type FruitColours = { [fruit: string]: string };

export const fruitColors: FruitColours = {
    apple: "red",
    banana: "yellow",
    kiwi: "green"
}
```

Using fruitColors, I need to make a list of all the fruits like:

```
const whatIWant = [apple, banana, kiwi] # Set of this
```

Thanks!

Edit:
Answer in comment works! Also, what if I had nested object like:

```
export const fruitColors: FruitColours = {
    a: {
      tomato: "red",
    }
   realFruits: {
     apple: "red",
  }
}
```

How do I get `whatIWant` in this case?

Comment: `Object.keys(fruitColors)`

Comment: If you need an actual `Set`, use `const whatIWant = new Set(Object.keys(fruitColors))`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This works! Also How do I do the updated part of the question?